# how can i access serial port data in c++ using wxwidgets

Tags: c++, serial-port, wxwidgets

i am electronics and communication engineering student. i am working on a project in which a microcontroller  send data to serial port of computer (asynchronously). 
i currently learning wxWidgets for my GUI work.

my question-
 is it  possible to do using wxWidgets to get data and display.  is it very difficult to implement this. 
i search for it but not get direct answer that how to implement this. so suggest me what  i need to read for this. and what alternative available to do this. i use windows 7.

i also need to upload this data to web server (it is needed later)

Comment: Not sure, but I thought wxWidgets just covers the GUI stuff. To access the COM port on the PC side you'll need to use a windows aware implementation for the serial IO. Boost.Asio may be helpful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html

Comment: After searching a lot for solution i decided to go with C# for gui and serial communication. it is very easy to implement it in c#.

Answer (score 3):

wxWidgets, to the best of my knowledge, does not implement serial I/O facilities.  There are other libraries available that provide this.  One of the best choices is probably boost::asio (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html)

Comment: did you know any tutorial about boost serial. they didn't provide any one. is there any other library. i also read some where that qt have serial libs. which one is easy for a c++ starter.

Comment: Boost::asio have some examples for http coounication as well.

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets is a cross-platform GUI framework.

Reading a serial port is nothing to do with the GUI, and not cross platform.

So wxWidgets has nothing to do with reading serial ports.

You can read/write from/to a serial port using the windows API.

[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) opens the port

[ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reads data from the port

Difficult?  Kinda!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself but there is [wxCTB](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/showcomp.php?name=wxCtb).

Comment: I suggested it and then tried it. The makefile isn't set up particularly well for MSVC and needs some tweaking to get working libraries other than static (linked statically to the CRT). I wasn't a fan of the port enumeration either, which was done using `GetDefaultCommConfig()` for ports COM1 to 100, rather than using the setup API. And it looks like they re-use their overlapped structure (at least if you manage to call Read() and Write() simulataneously). It looks OK, and must work for them since they have serial tools for Linux and Mac, but it looks like it needs some work under Windows.