# UART C/C++ code in wxWidgets for raspberryPI

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, codeblocks, wxwidgets, uart

I want to connect the module HC05 (with UART protocol) to Raspberry pi and see the receiving result on wxwidgets (code-blocks GUI).

where can i write UART code in wxwidgets?

How can i write each protocol in wxwidgets?

Comment: what is your exact question? The questions you asked are too broad to give a simple answer...

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets doesn't provide a uniform API for communicating with serial ports, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939513/how-can-i-access-serial-port-data-in-c-using-wxwidgets).

The Raspberry Pi is typically running a Linux distribution where serial ports are exposed as special device files such as `/dev/stty0`.  Consult your favorite Linux/Raspberry Pi documentation for information on how to configure serial port parameters.  Once configured, just read/write to the file in order to communicate with whatever devices is attached to the port.